# Show a image to visitor and delete that image from the server (on same page load)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

i just want to show a image to visitor in the same time delete this image from the server.

i tried this

show the image.
delete the record from database.
delete the image from server using `unlink()`.

```
echo "image";
$deleteimage = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE uniqueid= '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
unlink("../image path");
```

but when the page loads it deletes the file from server before it shows to visitor.

After searching i found that `PHP` is executed in the stack prior to rendering the output.

So how i do this using `ajax` `jquery`.
That is: load the page and show the image then execute the ajax code and delete the image.

Please give some ajax code. i am not familiar with `javascript` `(ajax,jquery)`

Comment: Read jQuery's  [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function .

Comment: You might consider creating a separate PHP script to serve the image itself then delete it, rather than handling it from the client in the page itself.

Comment: And where is your code? How do we know what is happening and how can you possibly expect help without that?

Comment: you need to unlink the image once image is successfully loaded in your html page..u can do it on image's onload event..once image is loaded send ajax request to unlink the image

Comment: how? any ajax code snippet? i am not familiar with javascript (ajax,jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function unlinkImage(src) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data:{
                src:src
            }
        }).done(function() {
            alert('done')
        });
    }
</script>
<img src='someimage.png' onload="unlinkImage('someimage.png')" />
</body>
</html>
```

and to delete on php side (delete.php):

```
<?php
    $res = unlink($_REQUEST['src']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With using `AJAX` it's possible what image will not be deleted. Connection problem or disabled `javascript`.

You need to do:

```
<img src="imgage.php?id=ID" />
```

and in `image.php` write:

```
// Select image source
$image = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT image FROM table WHERE uniqueid= '".intval($id)."'"), 0, 'image');

// Show image
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); // Or your image type
readfile($image);

// Delete image
$deleteimage = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE uniqueid= '".intval($id)."'") or die(mysql_error());
unlink($image);
```

Also don't use **mysql_***... You can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php%E2%80%8E).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Log In Page</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function ImageLoad(obj) {
                var src = $(obj).attr('src');
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data:{
                        imageSrc:src
                    },
                    dataType:"text",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#doneDiv').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/9rhympj35/agent_Photo.jpg" onload="ImageLoad(this);">
        <div id="doneDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In `test.php`, you could do,

```
<?php
    $res = unlink($_POST['imageSrc']);
    echo 'done'; 
    // or you can delete from database with your code

?>
```